# The question you are asking appears subjective and it is likely to be closed

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I tried to post a question on the main site with the title "How to compare recommendation letters" or "How to grade recommendation letters" and some similar titles from the view points of a selecting or hiring committee. But each time a blue box appears telling that

> The question you are asking appears subjective and it is likely to be closed

For this reason I didn't post my question, as I felt that the question is not appropriate for this site. My question is that is there a website on stackexchange or elsewhere, where I can ask this presumably subjective question?

Answer (score 4):

Usually, SE sites can allow [**constructive subjective questions**](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
> - tend to have long, not short, answers
> - have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
> - invite sharing experiences over opinions
> - insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
> - are more than just mindless social fun

If your questions falls under this category, and is relevant to Academia, you are welcome to post it on the main site.

Comment: +1. I'll add to this: [we are more open to subjective questions than some other SE sites](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/12/73). If it's [on-topic](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), ask it!

Comment: I wonder if in this case it's because of the word "recommendation" in the title, setting off the subjectivity-detector?